# read.delim() in R doesn't read .txt files keeping original values for variables

Tags: r

Hi everybody I am trying to load a .txt file in R and I got some troubles trying to make this. My original .txt file has the next structure (I can't add dput version because the loading of my file is wrong but I include variables and their values):

```
ID  Key.Number

1708888894  4222200000549012
0208823891  0002200000549111
0508823891  1717100000549111
0999923891  1717100000549111
0708888894  0002200000591111
```

It has the name "Testing.txt" and is formed by 2 variables `ID` and `Key.number`. In the .txt file variables are separated by tabulation (tab). For reading my file I used this code:

```
test=read.delim("Testing.txt")
test
```

And I got this:

```
          ID   Key.Number
1 1708888894 4.222200e+15
2  208823891 2.200001e+12
3  508823891 1.717100e+15
4  999923891 1.717100e+15
5  708888894 2.200001e+12
```

How you can see for `ID` column zero was omited and for `Key.Number` all values are in scientific format. Also I have tried with read.table but due to the nature of source file (Testing is only an example) column names are included in the first row and when I use col.names()=test[1,] I don't get the original names. I got this with `read.table()`

```
          V1               V2
1         ID       Key.Number
2 1708888894 4222200000549012
3 0208823891 0002200000549111
4 0508823891 1717100000549111
5 0999923891 1717100000549111
6 0708888894 0002200000591111
```

Many thanks for your help and your advice It is important for me.

Comment: Roland fixed it for you, but why in the world do you want to retain a blank row?  And are you sure you want the second column to be character strings rather than numeric?  What's displayed (for numeric data) is a format; the values are correctly stored in the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
DF <- read.table(text="ID  Key.Number

1708888894  4222200000549012
0208823891  0002200000549111
0508823891  1717100000549111
0999923891  1717100000549111
0708888894  0002200000591111", 
colClasses="character", header=TRUE, blank.lines.skip=FALSE)


#           ID       Key.Number
# 1                            
# 2 1708888894 4222200000549012
# 3 0208823891 0002200000549111
# 4 0508823891 1717100000549111
# 5 0999923891 1717100000549111
# 6 0708888894 0002200000591111
```

Comment: Thanks @Roland `colClasses="character"` was the key.

Comment: But when I tried with another file I got this error `Error in read.table("Myfile.txt", colClasses = "character", header = TRUE,  : 
  more columns than column names` @Roland How could I solve this.

Comment: The error message is descriptive. Possibly you have strings that include space characters. Specify tab as a column seperator.